# Hazelcast Retrying the connection

Tags: java, hazelcast

Why this message is repeated in the logs:

> hazelcast.web.ClusteredSessionService  : Retrying the connection!!

```
2018-05-06 13:25:19,328 INFO c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5703], bind any local is true
2018-05-06 13:25:29.333  INFO 9947 --- [.ensureInstance] c.hazelcast.web.ClusteredSessionService  : Retrying the connection!!
2018-05-06 13:25:29,333 INFO c.h.w.ClusteredSessionService Retrying the connection!!
2018-05-06 13:25:29.334  INFO 9947 --- [.ensureInstance] com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator    : Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2018-05-06 13:25:29,334 INFO c.h.c.XmlConfigLocator Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2018-05-06 13:25:29.342  INFO 9947 --- [.ensureInstance] c.hazelcast.web.HazelcastInstanceLoader  : Creating a new HazelcastInstance for session replication
2018-05-06 13:25:29,342 INFO c.h.w.HazelcastInstanceLoader Creating a new HazelcastInstance for session replication
2018-05-06 13:25:29.343  INFO 9947 --- [.ensureInstance] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5703], bind any local is true
```

hazelcast.xml

```
  <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8080/mancenter-3.3/</management-center>
    <network>
        <port>5080</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>192.168.1.3</member>
                <member>192.168.1.15</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>

    </network>
```

Hazelcast cacheConfiguration, HazelcastInstance methode:

```
 Config config = new ClasspathXmlConfig(String.format(Constants.HAZEL_XML_CONF_FILE, Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT));
            GroupConfig groupConfig = config.getGroupConfig();
            groupConfig.setName(env.getProperty("cache.group.name", String.class, "appName"));
            groupConfig.setPassword(env.getProperty("cache.group.password", String.class, "appName-password"));
            config.setGroupConfig(groupConfig);

            //TODO remove these lines and read from hazelcast-dev.xml
            config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("hazelcast.port")));
            config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.bind.any", "false");
            config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any", "false");
            config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.client.bind.any", "false");
            config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.client.bind", "false");
            config.setInstanceName(String.format("%s-%s", SABADBAN, Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT));
            System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
            return HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Comment: You should add some code, so that one can reproduce your issue ..

Comment: Hi i.Sadeghi, please post the code that's generating this error message so that someone here can help you debug. Thanks!

Comment: Erty Seidohl , I updated my question. please check it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove hazelcast.xml 
change Hazelcast cacheConfiguration, HazelcastInstance methode:

```
  @Bean
    @PostConstruct
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName(String.format("%s-%s", BROKER_PRO, env.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", String.class, "default")));
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.group.name", String.class, "appName"));
        config.getGroupConfig().setPassword(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.group.password", String.class, "appName-password"));
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.network.portAutoIncrement", Boolean.class, false));
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortCount(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.network.portCount", Integer.class, 1));
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.network.port", Integer.class, 5701));
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.network.join.multicastConfig.enable", Boolean.class, false));

        TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
        String[] ips = env.getProperty("cache.hazelcast.network.join.tcpIpConfig.members", String[].class, new String[]{});
        for (String ip : ips) {
            tcpIpConfig.addMember(ip);
        }
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);
        config.getMapConfigs().put("default", initializeDefaultMapConfig());
        return HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
```